# Work with multiple NICs/networks in Windows

Tags: networking

I'm searching for a solution to work on a Windows machine with multiple NICs/networks. While working within the network of a customer I tend to get a lot of problems. I need an internet connection for several things like git/sourcesafe/development system etc. but clients often can't offer internet access. So the solution is to use a mobilephone to connect to the internet and ethernet to access the client network/database.

Windows seems to be pretty random here. Sometimes everything works, some mintues later it trys to access the internet over the clients gataway or access the database via the internet. So I end up deactivting/activating NIC's all day long.

Is there some easy way to use the ethernet connection only to access the clients network and the mobile for everything else?

Comment: You should read about routing tables (and the *route* command), metrics and routing in general. In the end the number of interfaces does not matter, as long as you have unambiguous routes and one default gateway.

Comment: I tried to mess with the metric but windows seems not to try the second device when the first fails to access the destination. For the route add I'm missing a command to route everything except one network.

Answer (score 0):

From what you described I think this might help: turn off DHCP for the interface that connects to your customers network and set a static address for that (without a gateway). Then configure your other interface to use DHCP. This should set ONE default gateway (your phone) and all traffic will run through it, except endpoints in your customer's net.

BTW: You can only have one default gateway at a time, of course, but in your case the gateway that was set the latest won, so to speak.